# Method for setting up a recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, recurrence-relations

So I've got this homework task of setting up recurring relations from word problems and I've absolutely no idea of how to go about doing it.

The first and simplest problem is as follows:

> At a vending machine that only accepts 1€ and 2€ coins and doesn't give change and a customer can only buy items by adding one coin at a time. Let 1€ be the unit *n* and set up a recurrence relation for the number of ways a customer can pay for an item that costs *n* units. (Include the initial conditions)

Now I got the final solution from the answer key ($y_{n} - y_{n-1} - y_{n-2}=0$, initial conditions: $y_{1}=1, y_{2}=2$) and for low value things I could've thought it out by simply laying out all the different combinations, but how does one go about formally "proving" these things on paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not required to solve the recurrence, just to set it up, so in a sense there's nothing to prove.

As for the thinking behind the recurrence, $y_n$ represents the number of ways of paying for a item of cost $n$€ using $1$€ and $2$€ coins, where we care about the order the coins are put into the machine.

We have the simple cases ("initial conditions") that $y_1=1$ (can only pay $1$€ using a $1$€ coin), and $y_2=2$ (could pay with a $2$€ coin, or $1$€ followed by $1$€).

For the recurrence part, imagine the very last step of paying the $n$€ where $n\ge3$: if the last coin you pay with is $2$€, there are $y_{n-2}$ of paying the preceding coins. If the last coin you pay with is $1$€, there are $y_{n-1}$ ways of paying the preceding coins.  So the total number of ways of paying $n$€ is $y_{n-2}+y_{n-1}$, i.e. $y_n = y_{n-1}+y_{n-2}$.

Comment: Thank you! So would it generally be enough to simply write down the easy to find simple cases and and coming up with a formula on the first instance beyond those simple cases?

Comment: @Nincompoop: That's all you need to do for problems like this one. Later in your course you'll be doing new stuff, like trying to come up with a "closed" formula for $y_n$, i.e. a formula that lets you calculate $y_n$ without calculating every single of the sequence on the way.